# Using IF statement to append names to .csv file

Tags: bash, csv, if-statement

I have two files. One is Emails.csv and the other is a list of names.  I need to append names to email addresses containing that name.  My problem is that some lines will already have the desired `name1234@domain.com,name` I need.  File `names.txt` is in alphabetical order and `Emails.csv` is sorted by line length, longest first. How do I make appention (is that a word? It must be...) conditional?

```
#!/bin/bash
while read n; do
egrep -i "$n" Emails.csv
  if [ -z '"$n" | cut -d"," -f2' ]; then
     sed -i "s/$/,$n/" Emails.csv
  fi
done < names.txt
```

As my script is now, it just spits the content of Emails.csv.
I need a solution in Bash.

Comment: Change, `[ -z '"$n" | cut -d"," -f2' ]` to: `[ -z "$("$n" | cut -d"," -f2)" ]`

Comment: @user3439894 Thank you for the quick reply.  It now appends all names to all lines.

Comment: Are the names and email addresses in the same order in both files and do the files have the same lengths? I know you've already got an answer, but this would be a better question with examples of input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more convenient to find and replace using `sed`:

```
#! /bin/bash
while read n; do
    sed -i -r "s/^[^,]*$n[^,]+$/\0,$n/g" Emails.csv
done < names.txt
```

Comment: Works like a charm and is way more compact.  Thank You.